# Pass param to NOT strogly typed partial

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

If i have not strongly typed Partial and i want to pass parameter to that partial.

So if I  go like that:

```
@Html.Partial("Partials/Edit", @Model.Id)
```

How could i retrieve this param in partial, or there is no way for doing this if partial is not strongly typed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, unless your partial has a model of type object.

You may need to consider using ViewData or ViewBag.

Comment: Yes i see, i would better go with `@model int` on partial